# What do we say when glue does not stick anymore?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I want to know how can we says to a glue that does not stick anymore, can we say "**Glue has faded**"? is there any specific word in English for this phenomenon?

Comment: We say it's come unstuck.

Comment: _Fading_ is something that a sensory impression of some kind (a visual image or appearance, a memory, colours, sound, etc.) does. Glue doesn’t really _fade_ (that would mean it completely disappears from view), it’s still there. The binding property in it just stops binding.

Comment: Is the glue already applied to something that it's meant to be holding up/together - or is it still in the pot/tube/bottle that it was bought in?

Comment: I mean in case it's already applied to something

Comment: In that case I agree with John that the thing which the glue was meant to be holding has 'come unstuck' or 'fallen down'. I don't think there's a specific single word for what has happened to the glue itself, in that situation. If the glue were still in the glue-pot then FumbleFingers's suggestion that the glue has 'dried up' would be good.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help. Actually I was looking for a word for losing stickiness, regardless whether the thing is attached to something using glue or not.

Comment: @A E: Without context, you'd probably assume "dried up" glue is still in a glue-pot, tube, or something. But as I specifically flagged up by using self-sealed envelopes in my example, it's perfectly okay in other contexts where the "glue" is neither in a container nor currently sticking anything together.

Comment: I usually say "Mo#%$*! F^#@%^*@".

Comment: "Ye are the glue of the earth; but if the glue have lost his stickiness, wherewith shall it be stuck?  It is thenceforth good for nothing, but to be cast out, and to be trodden under the foot of men, whereupon, behold, it shall again be sticky, and shall make annoying noises as they walk, and thou shalt nevermore be able to remove it."

Comment: *a word for losing stickiness, regardless whether the thing is attached to something using glue* -- Just use *losing stickiness* or *becoming less sticky or unsticky or less adhesive*.

Comment: "Alas ... I am undone!" // In conversation, "It's lost its _stickum_" is not unknown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's any standard word for ***loss of stickiness*** [caused by the passage of time].

I acquired a large box of "self-seal" envelopes many years ago (the kind with two "tacky" surfaces like that on the back of a Post-it note, which stick when pressed together without needing to be wetted by licking). I'll usually say something like *"The gum has **dried out**"* when handing one to someone else, but it's not ideal because it implies you could "revive" the stickiness by wetting.

As you'll know if you've got any decades-old Post-it notes or rolls of Sellotape (US Scotch tape), *that* kind of ***loss of tackiness*** isn't fixed by a "just add water" approach. But in the same way that we speak of old oil-based paints ***drying out/up*** (and thus becoming thicker, or even solidifying), the same usage can apply to solvent-based liquid/paste glues.

---

If you want to use a more general term for important "functional" qualities lost over time, you could always say...

> *The glue has **degraded*** (or perhaps ***deteriorated*** [in storage]).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's the closest to my question.

Answer (score 4):

The glue-joint has failed.
The glue has failed.
The glue has lost all of its stickiness.
The glue isn't sticking any more.
The glue isn't holding any more.

Answer (score 0):

You have already said it, "The glue doesn't stick anymore".  That would be my first choice.  You could also say:

> - The glue has lost its adhesiveness/stickness.
> - The glue doesn't work anymore.
> - Its stickness seems to have expired.

Answer (score 0):

"When a glue doesn't stick anymore"

I would say "the glue is **degraded**".

**Debonded** could also be used to describe a glue that doesn't stick anymore.